# Can we pass an array as parameter in any function in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have a function to send mail to users and I want to pass one of its parameter as an array of ids.

Is this possible to do? If yes, how can it be done?

Suppose we have a function as:

```
function sendemail($id, $userid) {

}
```

In the example, `$id` should be an array.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can pass an array as an argument. It is copied by value (or [COW'd,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) which essentially means the same to you), so you can `array_pop()` (and similar) all you like on it and won't affect anything outside.

```
function sendemail($id, $userid){
    // ...
}

sendemail(array('a', 'b', 'c'), 10);
```

You can in fact only accept an array there by placing its type in the function's argument signature...

```
function sendemail(array $id, $userid){
    // ...
}
```

You can also call the function with its arguments as an array...

```
call_user_func_array('sendemail', array('argument1', 'argument2'));
```

Answer (score 13):

even more cool, you can pass a variable count of parameters to a function like this:

```
function sendmail(...$users){
   foreach($users as $user){

   }
}

sendmail('user1','user2','user3');
```

Comment: This better solution works with type safe e.g (Event ...$event)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can [safely pass an array as a parameter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can do that.

```
function sendemail($id_list,$userid){
    foreach($id_list as $id) {
        printf("$id\n"); // Will run twice, once outputting id1, then id2
    }
}

$idl = Array("id1", "id2");
$uid = "userID";
sendemail($idl, $uid);
```

Answer (score 4):

What should be clarified here.

Just pass the array when you call this function.

```
function sendemail($id,$userid){
Some Process....
}
$id=array(1,2);
sendmail($id,$userid);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function sendemail(Array $id,$userid){  // forces $id must be an array
Some Process....
}


$ids  = array(121,122,123);
sendmail($ids, $userId);
```

Answer (score 3):

I found Delcon answer helpful but I was looking for this

```
function sendmail($user1, $user2, $user3){
  echo $user1;
  echo $user2;
  echo $user3;
}

$users = array('user1','user2','user3');
sendmail(...$users);
```

Answer (score 2):

Its no different to any other variable, e.g.

```
function sendemail($id,$userid){
  echo $arr["foo"]; 
}

$arr = array("foo" => "bar");
sendemail($arr, $userid);
```

Comment: @vickirk : I edited your answer to correct mistake of $userid. hope you don't mind?

Comment: Note that you don't need to define it before calling the function. you could have done: `sendemail(array("foo" => "bar"), ...)`.

Comment: @Anonymous Loozah : when length of array is not too big.

Comment: @Gaurav : Yeah, but the array is probably going to be generated anyway.

Comment: Duh, I had just been checking £/$ rates, maybe my fingers got confused when my brain was asleep.  Cheers @Gaurav

Answer (score 2):

I composed this code as an example. Hope the idea works!

```
<?php
$friends = array('Robert', 'Louis', 'Ferdinand');
  function greetings($friends){
    echo "Greetings, $friends <br>";
  }
  foreach ($friends as $friend) {
  greetings($friend);
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In php 5, you can also hint the type of the passed variable:

```
function sendemail(array $id, $userid){
  //function body
}
```

See [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php).

Answer (score 1):

Since PHP is dynamically weakly typed, you can pass any variable to the function and the function will try to do its best with it.

Therefore, you can indeed pass arrays as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can pass arrays to a function.

```
$arr = array(“a” => “first”, “b” => “second”, “c” => “third”);

function user_defined($item, $key)
{
    echo $key.”-”.$item.”<br/>”;
} 

array_walk($arr, ‘user_defined’);
```

We can find more array functions here

http://skillrow.com/array-functions-in-php-part1/

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function takes_array($input)

{

    echo "$input[0] + $input[1] = ", $input[0]+$input[1];

}

?>
```