# Use array as argument list in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a PHP equivalent to the python `func(*[array])` feature to use the array as a series of arguments for the function? I can't seem to find one online.

Example usage in Python:

```
def f(a,b):
    print(a, b)

f('abc', 'def')
f(*['abc', 'def'])
```

Outputs

```
abc def
abc def
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: This is different to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459395/can-we-pass-an-array-as-parameter-in-any-function-in-php) because that question wants to use an array as a parameter, whereas I want to use an array as a series of parameters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we pass an array as parameter in any function in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459395/can-we-pass-an-array-as-parameter-in-any-function-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"..." is [Argument unpacking](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list), and can be used in the function definition, or the call

```
<?php
function add($a, $b) {
    return $a + $b;
}

echo add(...[1, 2])."\n";

$a = [1, 2];
echo add(...$a);
```

Given a  `...array()` as the function argument, collect the (remaining) arguments from the call into an array variable:

```
<?php
function sum(...$numbers) {
    $acc = 0;
    foreach ($numbers as $n) {
        $acc += $n;
    }
    return $acc;
}

echo sum(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Answer (score 2):

In PHP < 5.6 that would be `call_user_func_array('f', ['abc', 'def']);`

In 5.6+, you can do `f(...['abc', 'def']);` instead.